# How can I get the content of all cookies in "Set-Cookie" header returned by upstream in nginx

Tags: nginx, cookies, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Similar to the issue mentioned here https://forum.openresty.us/d/6503-get-content-of-second-set-cookie-header

I have an NGINX configuration that gets the cookies stored in Set-Cookie by the upstream auth_request and I need to return those set-cookie to the client, however whenever I try to return those cookies only the first set-cookie is returned to the client.

Below is an example configuration to demonstrate the issue

```
 location /auth/ {
    proxy_pass         http://auth/;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_redirect     off;
  }

  location / {
    auth_request       /auth/loggedin;
    auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
    proxy_set_header Cookie "$http_cookie; $auth_cookie";
    proxy_pass         http://someservice/;
  }
```

In my above example I expect that multiple cookies could be returned in a Set-Cookie header `a=12; PATH:"/", b=2; PATH:/"` and I want to pass whatever set-cookies come from the upstream service to clients browser via add_header. Currently only the cookie `a` is making it to the client and `b` is always missing.

Note:
I want it to be generic and so I can't grab the exact cookie names from a header.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Bad news: you can't do it since cookies are set using multiple `Set-Cookie` headers and only the first one is accessible using `$upstream_http_set_cookie` variable (as any other multiple header with a few exceptions), you can take a look [here](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1843) (although I didn't consider it as a bug). Unlike most other headers that can be folded in one, `Set-Cookie` is a special case (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6375214/7121513) answer and comments below for more details why is it a special case).

Comment: However since you mentioned OpenResty in your question, there are some good news too: it is possible to do it using lua module. Bad news: it won't work with the `auth_request` location, it is imposible to add `lua_...` handlers to such a location. Good news: similar functionality can be implemented using [`ngx.location.capture`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture) API call. So if the OpenResty solution is suitable for you, I can give you such an answer.

Comment: Thank you @IvanShatsky for your detailed answer with links. I was afraid that would be the case and it makes sense to me why that is the case. I have a couple of alternatives to handling this use case so I'm going to continue with them for now. If you would like to use your replies as an answer I would be more than happy to mark the replies as the correct answer.

Comment: Having eight times more answers than questions, I decided you deserve more than just _It is impossible because..._ so I wrote the code. It was an interesting challenge and a nice chance to remember lua which I didn't use for a few years. Even if you don't use it maybe it will help someone else. I like your question, take my +1 ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it is impossible to do it the way you want to. Setting cookies using multiple `Set-Cookie` header is a common approach, the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) on `Set-Cookie` header explicitly says that:

> To send multiple cookies, multiple `Set-Cookie` headers should be sent in the same response.

When multiple headers with the same name are received from the upstream, only the first one is accessible using `$upstream_http_<header_name>` variable (with a few exceptions, e.g. `Cache-Control` one, if I remember correctly). There is a [ticket](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1843) for that on nginx bug tracker (although I did't consider it a bug). `Set-Cookie` header is really a special case that can't be folded in opposite to many other headers, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6375214/7121513) answer and comments below it to see why is it so. (Of course, you are still free to use any `$upstream_cookie_<cookie_name>` per-cookie variable).

However it is possible to do it using OpenResty (mentioned in your question) or [`lua-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module). The bad news, it will be incompatible with the `auth_request` directive since it is impossible to add those `lua_...` handlers to the auth location (or any other subrequest location that can be used, e.g., by `add_before_body` or `add_after_body` directives from the [`ngx_http_addition_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_addition_module.html)). You didn't get an error, but those handlers won't be fired on a subrequest. The good news, functionality similar to `auth_request` can be implemented using [`ngx.location.capture`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture) API call.

So if using `nginx-lua-module` is suitable for you (and if it isn't, maybe the solution will help some others), this can be done the following way:

```lua
location /auth/ {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://auth/;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location / {
    # -- this one is taken from the official lua-nginx-module documentation example
    # -- see https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#access_by_lua
    access_by_lua_block {
        local res = ngx.location.capture("/auth/loggedin", {body = ""})
        if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
            ngx.ctx.auth_cookies = res.header["Set-Cookie"]
            return
        end
        if res.status == ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN then
            ngx.exit(res.status)
        end
        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }

    # -- it doesn't matter where the 'proxy_pass' line actually would be, it doesn't change the workflow
    # -- see https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2137369/15272097/77d1c09e-1a37-11e6-97ef-d9767035fc3e.png
    proxy_pass http://someservice/;

    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        local function merge_cookies(a, b)
            local c = a or b
            -- if either "a" or "b" is empty, "c" already has the required result
            if (a and b) == nil then return c end
            -- neither "a" nor "b" are empty, result will be a table, "c" now equals to "a"
            -- if "c" is a string, lets made it a table instead
            if type(c) == "string" then c = {c} end
            -- append "b" to "c"
            if type(b) == "string" then table.insert(c, b) else
                for _, v in ipairs(b) do table.insert(c, v) end
            end
            return c
        end
        ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = merge_cookies(ngx.header["Set-Cookie"], ngx.ctx.auth_cookies)
    }
}
```

This code does not check possible cookie names intersection, or it will be **much** more complex. However I think (not checked this on practice) that it doesn't really matter because even if a two `Set-Cookie` requests with the same cookie name but different values will be returned to the client, the last one will be used. This code makes `Set-Cookie` requests from the auth server arriving after the `Set-Cookie` requests from the main upstream. To do the opposite you'd need to change the

```
ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = merge_cookies(ngx.header["Set-Cookie"], ngx.ctx.auth_cookies)
```

line to the

```
ngx.header["Set-Cookie"] = merge_cookies(ngx.ctx.auth_cookies, ngx.header["Set-Cookie"])
```

Special thanks to the [@wilsonzlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6249022/wilsonzlin) for the extremely helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016867/how-come-i-cannot-set-multiple-cookies/44016904#44016904) on working with the `ngx.header["Set-Cookie"]` table.

**Update**

Though you didn't mention it in your question, looking at your example I saw you not only want to pass the `Set-Cookie` headers to the client but also to send those cookies to the `someservice` upstream. Again, you are trying to do it a wrong way. Using `proxy_set_header Cookie "$http_cookie; $auth_cookie";` you are appending those cookies including their attributes like `Path`, `Max-Age`, etc. while the `Cookie` header should contain only the `name=value` pairs. Well, using the `lua-nginx-module` this is also posible. You'd need to change the above `access_by_lua_block` to the following one.

```lua
access_by_lua_block {

    local res = ngx.location.capture("/auth/loggedin", {body = ""})
    if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
        ngx.ctx.auth_cookies = res.header["Set-Cookie"]

        if ngx.ctx.auth_cookies then

            -- helper functions
            -- strip all Set-Cookie attributes, e.g. "Name=value; Path=/; Max-Age=2592000" => "Name=value"
            local function strip_attributes(cookie)
                return string.match(cookie, "[^;]+")
            end
            -- iterator for use in "for in" loop, works both with strings and tables
            local function iterate_cookies(cookies)
                local i = 0
                return function()
                    i = i + 1
                    if type(cookies) == "string" then
                        if i == 1 then return strip_attributes(cookies) end
                    elseif type(cookies) == "table" then
                        if cookies[i] then return strip_attributes(cookies[i]) end
                    end
                end
            end

            local cookies = ngx.req.get_headers()["Cookie"]
            -- at the first loop iteration separator should be an empty string if client browser send no cookies or "; " otherwise
            local separator = cookies and "; " or ""
            -- if there are no cookies in original request, make "cookies" variable an empty string instead of nil to prevent errors
            cookies = cookies or ""

            for cookie in iterate_cookies(ngx.ctx.auth_cookies) do
                cookies = cookies .. separator .. cookie
                -- next separator definitely should be a "; "
                separator = "; "
            end

            ngx.req.set_header("Cookie", cookies)

        end

        return
    end
    if res.status == ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN then
        ngx.exit(res.status)
    end
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
}
```

All the above examples are tested (using OpenResty 1.17.8.2) and confirmed to be workable.

Comment: I get errors with this regarding http2.

Comment: @TheFool Indeed, this was tested with HTTP/1.1. Looks like `ngx.location.capture` is [incompatible](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/1195#issuecomment-346410275) with HTTP/2. I saw your recent questions already, and I can tell you after all the testing I did answering this question there is no way to add the LUA handler to the auth location - it just didn't get called.

Comment: @TheFool I don't have an HTTP/2 environment to test this code right now. I'd try to give it a test in a few days.

Comment: In terms of the other question, I also was not able to use regular `add_header`. But probably not the right place to discuss this here.

Answer (score 0):

I found no other way but to use the lua module. This should partially answer your question, it does answer the question "How do I get all the Set-Cookie headers".

```
location / {
    log_by_lua_block {
        local cookies = ngx.resp.get_headers()["Set-Cookie"]
        if cookies~=nil then
            ngx.log(ngx.ERR, table.concat(cookies, ','))
        end
    }
...
}
```

If you use different directives than `log_by_lua_block` I can't guarantee you'll be able to see that particular header, with `access_by_lua_block` I couldn't.
If you want to pass the stuff to the client, maybe `log_by_lua_block` is a bit late in the workflow, maybe try an earlier one.